# ExpressJS Object Not Defined Templating Error

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs, referenceerror

I am not sure why I'm getting a `ReferenceError: Object not defined` error, when I'm passing my object for use within my view. I am running two routes through one view. One is for creating a record, with the other being used to edit records via POST method. The way I am letting my view know if content should be displayed within my form fields with by using a templated if/else statement. What is the cause for my error to appear when I'm calling `blogpost : blogpost` within my routes file?

error:

```
ReferenceError: blogpost is not defined
   at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/app/routes.js:128:26
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
   at next (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
   at isLoggedIn (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/app/routes.js:307:16)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
   at next (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
   at next (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:94:14)
   at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
   at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:24
```

Here is the part of my route that is experiencing the error:

```
router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.featureImage = req.body.featureImage; // set the blog image
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method


        .get(isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/blogpost-create', {
              blogpost : blogpost
            });
        });
```

How I'm using my `blogpost` object within my view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.5/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Blog Create</h1>

            <% if(blogpost && blogpost.blogUrl) { %> 

                <form action="/admin/posts/edit/<%= blogpost.blogUrl %>" method="POST">
                Header Image: <input type="file" id="files">
                <p id="status">Please select a file</p>
                <div id="preview"><img src="<%= blogpost.featureImage %>"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="feature-image" name="featureImage" value="/images/event-placeholder.png" />
                Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= blogpost.title %>"><br>
                Author: 
                    <select name="author">
                        <option value="Author">Connor Phillips</option>
                    </select><br>
                Category: 
                    <select name="category">
                        <option value="Analytics/SEO/SEM">Analytics/SEO/SEM</option>
                        <option value="Advice">Advice</option>
                        <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                        <option value="Thoughts">Thoughts</option>
                    </select><br>
                Tagline: <input type="text" maxlength="160" name="tagline" value="<%= blogpost.tagline %>"><br>
                Content:<br>
                <textarea name="content" id="blog-editor" rows="10" cols="80">
                    <%= blogpost.content %>
                </textarea>
                <br>
                Tags: <input type="text" name="tags">
                <br>

                <% } else { %>


                <form action="/admin/posts/create" method="POST">
                Header Image: <input type="file" id="files"/>
                <p id="status">Please select a file</p>
                <div id="preview"><img src="/images/event-placeholder.png"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="feature-image" name="featureImage" value="/images/event-placeholder.png" />
                Title: <input type="text" name="title"></input><br>
                Author: 
                    <select name="author">
                        <option value="Author">Test</option>
                    </select><br>
                Category: 
                    <select name="category">
                        <option value="Test">Test</option>
                        <option value="Test">Test</option>
                        <option value="Test">Test</option>
                        <option value="Test">Test</option>
                    </select><br>
                Tagline: <input type="text" maxlength="160" name="tagline"><br>
                Content:<br>
                <textarea name="content" id="blog-editor" rows="10" cols="80">

                </textarea>
                <br>
                Tags: <input type="text" name="tags">
                <br>

                <% } %>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="blog-editor"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.

                CKEDITOR.replace( 'blog-editor' );
                CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;   
                CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = false;
                CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek= false;
                CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin= false;  
                CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
                CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push = '/<\#[\s\S]*#\#>/g';



    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/s3upload.js" async></script>

    <script>
        console.log("S3 Function Launched");

        function s3_upload(){
            var status_elem = document.getElementById("status");
            var url_elem = document.getElementById("feature-image");
            var preview_elem = document.getElementById("preview");
            var s3upload = new S3Upload({
                file_dom_selector: 'files',
                s3_sign_put_url: '/sign_s3',
                onProgress: function(percent, message) {
                    status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload progress: ' + percent + '% ' + message;
                },
                onFinishS3Put: function(public_url) {
                    status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload completed. Uploaded to: '+ public_url;
                    url_elem.value = public_url;
                    console.log(public_url);
                    preview_elem.innerHTML = '<img src="'+public_url+'" style="width:300px;" />';
                },
                onError: function(status) {
                    status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload error: ' + status;
                    console.log(status_elem.innerHTML);
                }
            });
        }
        /*
        * Listen for file selection:
        */
        (function() {

            var input_element = document.getElementById("files");
            input_element.onchange = s3_upload;
        })();
    </script>


    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogpost is undefined because it is not defined inside the scope you're calling it from. You defined var blogpost = new Blogpost(); inside the .post() definition, but not in the .get(). I think you are trying to pass the blogpost you created inside the /post route into the /get route, but the object will not be available after the /redirect completes.